# Slow PHP query from MYSQL when search between dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I am using Codeigniter and currently facing extremely slow searching result when i try to query a list of DB via my search engine (php system).  I believe the problem is much related with my query coding as the rest of the pages that shows the DB are loading fast but not when I search DB between dates. The page is like loading more than 10 minutes when I perform the search. Please check is it something wrong with my coding or can any expert please provide me a better suggestion to improve my coding:

```
public function get_transaction_record($search,$per_pg,$offset){
        $fill  = array((int)1);
        $temp  = array();
        $data  = array();
        $sQuery = "SELECT t.*,p.product_name,d.deposit_id,w.withdrawal_id,m.username,m.lucky_id,m.contact_no,u.username as admin,
                    b.name as bankname,b.holder_name, d.promo as prm, m.fullname, d.turnover as tover
                    FROM tbl_transaction t
                    INNER JOIN tbl_product p ON t.product_id = p.product_id
                    INNER JOIN tbl_member m ON m.member_id = t.member_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_deposit d ON t.transaction_id = d.transaction_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_withdrawal w ON t.transaction_id = w.transaction_id
                    INNER JOIN tbl_banks b ON t.bank_id = b.bankID
                                              LEFT JOIN tbl_promotion pro ON pro.promotion_id = d.promotion_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user u ON u.user_id = t.admin_id WHERE 1 = ?  AND t.status != 9";

        if( strlen($search['date_from']) > 0  && strlen($search['date_to']) > 0  ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND date(t.date_create) BETWEEN ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['date_from']);

            $sQuery .= ' AND ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['date_to']);
        }else{
            if( strlen($search['date_from']) > 0 ){
                $sQuery .= ' AND date(t.date_create) = ? ';
                array_push($fill,$search['date_from']);
            }
            if( strlen($search['date_to']) > 0 ){
                $sQuery .= ' AND date(t.date_create) = ? ';
                array_push($fill,$search['date_to']);
            }
        }

        if( strlen($search['status']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND t.status = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['status']);
        }
                    if( strlen($search['contact_no']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND m.contact_no LIKE "%"?"%" ';
            array_push($fill,$search['contact_no']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['fullname']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND m.fullname LIKE "%"?"%" ';
            array_push($fill,$search['fullname']);
        }
        if( strlen($search['username']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND m.username LIKE "%"?"%" ';
            array_push($fill,$search['username']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['lucky_id']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND m.lucky_id = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['lucky_id']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['email']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND m.email LIKE "%"?"%" ';
            array_push($fill,$search['email']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['user_id']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND t.admin_id = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['user_id']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['product_id']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND t.product_id = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['product_id']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['bankID']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND t.bank_id = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['bankID']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['type']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND t.type = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['type']);
        }

        if( strlen($search['bankid2']) > 0 ){
            $sQuery .= ' AND w.bankid2 = ? ';
            array_push($fill,$search['bankid2']);
        }

    //    $sQuery .= " ORDER BY t.date_create DESC LIMIT ?,? ";
            $sQuery .= " ORDER BY t.date_create DESC LIMIT ?,? ";
        // $sQuery .= " ORDER BY CASE t.status WHEN 0 THEN 0 WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN -1 THEN 9 END, t.date_create DESC LIMIT ?,? ";
        array_push($fill,(int)$offset,(int)$per_pg);

        $query  = $this->db->query($sQuery, $fill );
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($query->result() as $rows):
                $temp['bankname']       = $rows->bankname;
                $temp['holder_name']    = $rows->holder_name;
                $temp['ref']            = $rows->ref;
                $temp['username']       = $rows->username;
                $temp['fullname']       = $rows->fullname;
                $temp['lucky_id']       = $rows->lucky_id;
                $temp['admin']          = $rows->admin;
                $temp['contact_no']     = $rows->contact_no;
                $temp['product_name']   = $rows->product_name;
                                    $temp['promo']   = $rows->promo;
                $temp['transaction_id'] = $rows->transaction_id;

                $temp['member_id']      = $rows->member_id;
                $temp['type']           = $rows->type;
                $temp['product_id']     = $rows->product_id;
                $temp['deposit_id']     = $rows->deposit_id;
                $temp['withdrawal_id']  = $rows->withdrawal_id;
                $temp['amount']         = $rows->amount;
                                    $temp['turnover']         = $rows->turnover;
                $temp['status']         = $rows->status;
                $temp['remark']         = $rows->remark;
                $temp['day']            = $rows->day;
                $temp['month']          = $rows->month;
                $temp['year']           = $rows->year;
                $temp['date_create']    = $rows->date_create;
                $temp['date_update']    = $rows->date_update;
                $temp['create_by']      = $rows->create_by;
                                    $temp['prm']            = $rows->prm;
                                    $temp['tover']            = $rows->tover;
                                    if($rows->promotion_id > 0){
                                            $temp['promo'] = $this->get_promotion_details($rows->promotion_id);
                                    }else{
                                            $temp['promo'] = NULL;
                                    }
                array_push($data, $temp);
            endforeach;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Updated code as above

[IMG FOR tbl_transaction SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djh8N.png)

Thanks.

Comment: When you ask for query optimization help, always post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all the tables in your query, and the `EXPLAIN` for the query. And don't make us trace your code to figure out the final SQL. Show us the SQL, not the code that builds the SQL string.

Comment: @Randall a very long list as the system involved more than 10k rows of db entry daily. But it does load quite quick if i view the page without searching a certain date.

Comment: `date()` cannot use an index

Comment: @BillKarwin hold on, there's couple tables join together, i will try to show the example

Comment: I usually punt and store dates as bigints, and then searching between two dates is very quick. It may not be elegant, but I really dislike mysql's "date" defined fields. Personal taste I guess.

Comment: @Strawberry any suggestion for amending that index?

Comment: @Randall so, your suggestion is change my Mysql table's date into bigints instead?

Comment: No no no... I dont suggest that :) Thats a overhaul of your system, and how you store and retrieve/use those values. I was just mentioning, a possible worst case scenario. (thus why I didnt offer it in as an Answer)

Comment: @BillKarwin I have added the main db table in img file that using the coding above, the rest table are the supporting for all the IDs that shown in the enclosed db table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have no indexes defined for your transaction table. So any searches are forced to do a table-scan. It's important to use indexes to speed up searches.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). Or the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

This is probably the most important index for you to create:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_transaction ADD INDEX (create_date);
```

But even after you have an index, when you try to search on an expression like the following, it can't use the index.

```
date(t.date_create) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

You have to rewrite it so the indexed column is alone:

```
t.date_create BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

But this means you want the first parameter to be "floored" to time 00:00:00 and the second parameter to be "ceilinged" to time 23:59:59, to make sure the date_create with any time component matches the date range you want it to match.

```
if( strlen($search['date_from']) > 0  && strlen($search['date_to']) > 0  ){
    $from = search['date_from'] . ' 00:00:00'; 
    $to   = search['date_to']   . ' 23:59:59'; 

    $sQuery .= ' AND t.date_create BETWEEN ? AND ?';
    array_push($fill,$from);
    array_push($fill,$to);
}
```

Likewise, even for the searches for one specific date, you still have to do a range:

```
else if( strlen($search['date_from']) > 0 ){
    $from = search['date_from'] . ' 00:00:00'; 
    $to   = search['date_from'] . ' 23:59:59'; 

    $sQuery .= ' AND t.date_create BETWEEN ? AND ?';
    array_push($fill,$from);
    array_push($fill,$to);
}
```

If you read my presentation on designing indexes, you will have noticed that a range condition like the one on your create_date means any subsequent columns in the index won't help the search. You can use multi-column indexes, but all columns involved in equality conditions must be to the left in the index.

Also, you have multiple conditions that may or may not be present, based on the user's search criteria. This is also hard to optimize, because an indexed search only uses the columns of the index left-to-right. If you skip a column because the search doesn't need it, the subsequent columns won't help.

Another type of condition in your search is text pattern matching with `LIKE '%'?''`, instead of equality conditions. These `LIKE` searches can't use a conventional index, but they can use a special [fulltext search index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). I have a presentation for that too: [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql). Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8yA8C3CZOc